# Simple 3d animation in famo.us

Tags: famo.us

I am new to famo.us. I am looking to build a simple 3d animation where a object(box) keeps rotating with its color and opacity changing. Can someone suggest me some ideas on how to proceed ? I tried to use physics engine but with no success.

Comment: why don't you just use the starter-kit rotating logo and start working from there?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these resources on physics and property transitions:

- [Happy Boxes - Physics engine demo](https://github.com/talves/famous-happy-boxes)
- [Transition Button – PropertyTransitionable](http://famousco.de/2014/07/transition-button-ripple-effect/)
- [Unofficial list of famo.us resources](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-resources)